# Tabbed layout & Webviews

Tags: android, webview

Currently im running  a tabbed layout...But in the tabs i would like to have webviews...

The problem that im getting is that for some reason because of the tabs shouldOverrideUrlLoading does not work and it still opens the browser...

Here is my source:

My main Activity:

```
package app.numbers4sports.com;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TabHost;

    public class numbers4sports extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CounterActivity.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("counter").setIndicator("COUNTER",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_counter))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HelpActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("help").setIndicator("HELP",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_help))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HomeActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("ORDER",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_home))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }



    }
```

My Home activity (first webview):

```
package app.numbers4sports.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.numbers4sports.com");
    }
    private class abcd extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I can't answer you question but for reference, 'package app.numbers4sports.com' is the wrong way to name your package. Package names should be in reverse to a domain name. In other words it's a top-down format, e.g., 'package com.numbers4sports.app'

Comment: @MisterSquonk i will fix that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a WebView.setWebViewClient() in your code?

Comment: GREAT! Thanks! Yeah that was it i forgot that! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> mWebView.**setWebViewClient()** {
>       @Override
>       // Show in WebView instead of Browser
>       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
>           {
>               view.loadUrl(url);
>               return true;
>           }
>   }

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your `WebViewClient` is placed correctly
And make sure that you write `return true;`.